# Controlling emacs dumb-terminal

Tags: c++, terminal, emacs, gdb, ncurses

I am writing my own lisp interpreter in C++ using emacs as editor and for debugging with gdb. I use termios and escape sequence, to have control about input, so that it is possible to edit a lisp-command in a terminal. My aim is, that my lisp-interpreter should also run in emacs with "M-x run-lisp" and in an ansi-terminal. The problem I have, when I use the debugger, emacs use his own dumb-terminal which don't work with escape-sequences, so debugging becomes difficulty. 
I want to know, how it it possible to get control to the dumb-terminal or eterm, or if it is not possible, how can I temporarily control emacs from my program? Maybe if the dumb-terminal is started to run, that I can switch to another terminal like ansi-term in emacs without changing the .emacs file.
If I use the lisp-interpreter sbcl or gcl in emacs with

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl");
```

or

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "gcl");
```

in .emacs and invoke it in emacs with M-x run-lisp
it seems, that emacs use the dumb-terminal.

and sbcl it is able to edit a lisp-command like

```
* (* 3
4 )
```

also you can do this in gcl

```
> (+ 8
   5
   7
   6
  )
```

over any lines using arrow-keys, backspace and del to edit and Carriage Return evaluate the lisp-command only, until the round brackets "(" and ")" are correctly set.

If sbcl or gcl can do this, there must be a way to control the dumb-terminal of emacs, using arrow-keys, backspace and maybe changing the input after using Carriage-Return when the lisp-command is not finished.

I also recognised, that sbcl are not editible in ansi-terminals but in emacs dumb-terminal. When I experimented with this dumb-terminal, I was also able to edit a line, until Carriage-Return is pressed. After it is pressed, the input-buffer is empty. Maybe the solution is, if the line is after Carriage-Return not finished, I must find a way, to refill this buffer with the old information again. Maybe if I have success with it, I can edit the line until to the next Carriage-Return. But there is another problem! The unfinished line is printed at the next line position. It must be printed at his old position, where I started the input.

Now I can do this only in ansi-terminal with escape sequences and run into troubles during debugging in emacs.

If I want to force to use escape-sequences or ncurses, there I am looking for a way, temporarily without changing the .emacs-file to start another terminal in emacs. Especially if I am debugging. Maybe the dumb-terminal must be killed and an ansi-term-terminal begin to start. This is generally useful, if you debug code, which uses ncurses or escape-sequences in different terminal-programs.

Comment: `run-lisp` is using `comint` and so you're not editing the input commands via the inferior process, but rather you are just editing text in an Emacs buffer, and then `comint-send-input` is used to send the command to the process (`inferior-lisp-mode-map` binds `RET` to `comint-send-input`).  `inferior-lisp-mode` configures comint.

Comment: If the escape sequences in question are for colour, then `C-h v ansi-color-for-comint-mode` might be useful.

Comment: As you've ascertained, `inferior-lisp-mode` (and comint generally) is no help if you need the likes of `ncurses`.  Using `term` is indeed the normal way to go for that.

Comment: You might want to look into https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/ and its [debugging support](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Debugger.html).

Comment: I tested sbcl and gcl again and editing does not work properly after the first Carriage Return of an unfinished command. I reached the same level in editing a command line like if you run sbcl or gcl under emacs.  For testing terminal-programs using escape sequences via gdb in emacs, it is better to send the output via /dev/tty.. to a free terminal, instead of using the dumb-terminal of emacs.